# API Call Time Regulation in PHP

Tags: php, api, time, cron

So I am not 100% sure how to ask this. I am building a website that will make several calls to an API to collect and store information. No surprise there. After some testing and theory, I can easily bust the 30 calls per second limit imposed on the API IF the site were to gather as much traffic as I am predicting it will. The calls will be initiated by a cron. The script will then make 30ish calls to the API. I need a way of slowing the script down so that maybe 5 or so calls are made per second, the data is stored in a database and the script is finished and then ran again by crontab at the top of the next minute. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank You,
Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Speed

Slowing things down is easy: add some [usleep()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php) calls between each API call. You could hardcode the calls to say, 1/5th a second, to do at most 5 in a second, or you could record how many calls you're making and only start slowing down when needed.

Even simpler, you could make 5 calls, wait 1 second, then make another 5 calls.

This works regardless of how often you invoke the script.

#### Preventing concurrent script execution

The other thing to worry about is overlapping calls (running the script multiple times concurrently). Obviously it doesn't matter what timing you put in, if you end up having the script run multiple times.

If you invoke the script infrequently enough, and are absolutely sure it won't overlap, then you may be able to get away with doing nothing.

To be sure though, you could implement a locking mechanism. This can be as simple as a lock file that you check for when the script starts. If it exists, exit. Otherwise, create the lock file, run the script, then delete the lock file. As a fail-safe, you can not just check it exists, but also that it was created within the past hour (or whatever safety margin you want to use).